# How do I nest multiple ViewModels in a top level ViewModel, in a sort of hierarchy that can be dispersed throughout my Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, hierarchy

Right now I have a rather large `ViewModel` called `MainViewModel`, that contains a lot of commands and properties that could be organized into more reasonably named ViewModels.

I however, only have one window, and so need to be able to cherry-pick the valid data and Commands from each of the SubViewModels....

I figure this could be achieved using properties, but I'm not so sure how to approach this in the XAML. (Or if there is an implication in the ViewModels themselves)

I realize that I can set the `DataContext` on SubViews as I see fit, but I want to avoid having my View dictate the hierarchy/organization of my ViewModels.

Ex. pseudo code

```
SubAViewModel mvmB = new SubBViewModel();
SubAViewModel mvmA = new SubAViewModel();
MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel( mvmA, mvmB );

<Window DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">

    //This is clearly wrong but is sort of what I am trying to achieve
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=MainViewModel.SubAVM.TargetCmd}" />
```

It's entirely possible that a `MenuItem` or some other `UserControl` would want to access a Command in `SubBViewModel` and a property in `SubAViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the data context of the View to the MainViewModel and you expose the SubAVM as a property like this one:

```
public SubViewModel SubAVM { 
   get { 
      return subAVM;
   }
   set{
   if (subAVM == value)
   {
      return;
   }
   subAVM = value; //implement the OnPropertyChanged ...
   }
}
```

Of course the Path on a MenuItem would be SubAVM.TargetCmd as by the dependency hierarchy the main path is already MainViewModel for a Menu.